# Vue JS Dynamic component unit test is failed to mount component

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am using [Dynamic & Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) which is working fine. but while testing it with shallow mount using [Vue-test-util](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api). i am getting an warning as follows
`[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

`<component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>`

my test cases are passing but with above warning. how can i test vue component having dynamic component/s? could anyone please advise?

Comment: Have you tried flushing any promises?